# Is it common for such basic TTL gate chips as 74LS32, '08, and '86 to be broken?

Tags: logic-gates, ttl, failure

I have too many failures with very basic gate chips, while the more complex chips seem to keep working fine. And I find that very puzzling. These aren't even CMOS where I know that a static discharge can cause damage. But have just again determined a 74LS32 quad 2-input OR gate, one of the more basic chips, started to behave like an AND gate. I also threw away a '08 AND chip the other day. And now I'm having an '86 XOR with clearly one input high the other input low and still gives me a low output. And now I plugged in another one from that batch, says "Indonesia" and it too seems a failure. I don't understand how I have so many bad chips, and all those common simple ones, while counters, and muxes and RAM and tri-state buffers, and other stuff is all working.

What is your experience with TTL chip failures? Did you also find that when an OR chip fails it seems to behave like an AND?

Comment: Maybe some pics of some of the failed ICs?

Comment: What voltage are you running them at?

Comment: Are you buying your parts from a reputable vendor?

Comment: If you are finding that many parts apparently faulty, you must be doing something wrong.  Show schematics of the circuits where these parts fail.  Note that 74LS inputs source current, and you must sink significant current for the part to consider the input as a Low - you would need 500 Ohms or lessto Ground to make a Low (or a solid ground).

Comment: Ground-bounce can damage any IC. Absence of bypass capacitors can lead to wicked ground-bounce. 74LSxx is less sensitive to static, but it is not immune to static damage. 74Fxx is very sensitive to static, though it is very fast TTL.

Comment: It may be how you use the chips. For instance, LSTTL chips need stronger drive on its inputs compared to CMOS chips, and an unconnected LSTTL input typically floats high at logic 1.

Answer (score 1):

I used 74LS logic gates on several projects before 74HC(T) came along.

The 74LS outputs were damaged easily by accidental shorts or overloads. Such shorts came about through careless use of 'scope/DMM probes, bad wiring in wire-wrapped boards or lash-ups and so on. I saw ICs with visible heat damage or even sections of package cracked off by it.

In comparison, outputs for the modern logic gate families and CPLDs/FPGAs I've used since the late 90's or so are pretty tough. Although an accidental short still makes my heart jump, I've not yet seen an IC damaged by it.

So this needs you to look into how you are using these 74LS ICs. Review your circuit and implementation and check that you have no overloads, outputs connected to outputs and so forth. Look into your debugging practices.

If the 74LS ICs are operating within their published specifications at all times, including during power-up, power-down and unpowered, then you need to consider the quality of the supplied parts.

Comment: Since I am primarily building experimental circuits on breadboards, I certainly have the occasional mis-wiring, and I had found over all that the chips were very resilient to all sorts of "abuse". This is why I am so surprised that the only failures I ever seem to get are those very basic gates, even though I don't think I'm using those most frequently. I think some are "new" from the shop even, these "indonesia" XOR chips seem to have come bad from the store.